# Mirror vertex selection

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, shortcut, mirror, vertex-groups

Let's say I have selected some vertexes:
[image]

How do I mirror this selection (in x axis) so I can select the other side (same vertices assuming my mesh is symmetric) 
I just want to select the other side not do any operations.

Comment: this is not answer, yes
its mirror not for selected dots

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choose [Mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/mirror.html) from the Select menu and check the Extend option.

Comment: I can't find the extend option, selecting mirror in select menu attempts to mirror and fails with error "0 vertices mirrored"

Comment: @Arijoon *Extend* option is in Last Operator panel, either open Toolshelf or press `F6`. Although it should work without that the option - it will only add mirrored selection to your original one. Check that you don't use Mirror modifier

Comment: Does Blender 2.8 still have this feature?

Comment: I don't see that in blender 2.8

Comment: I see it in 2.82(.7)a  if you select and then click Select>'Mirror Select' after using symmetric sculpting it says something like "Warning: 0 vertices mirrored, 5139 failed" so it is not able to understand exactly where it's partner vertices are or edges or faces. So the real answer is "no it does not" create a double selection brush (pressing 'c' for instance) as you might expect or hope. Another one for the suggestion box. I guess you'd have to use the mirror modifier route to do that but there should be a sculpt brush to do what you want if that be the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to edit mode
2. Go under the *modifiers* tab and add modifier. Look for the Mirror option under generate.
3. Ensure that the X-axis is checked. Click on the vertices buttons under the Mirror modifier and you should be able to see it in your 3D view.
4. To apply the mirrored vertices click *Apply*.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question